# Why "Method not found: 'Void System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException..ctor" after package update?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget-package, visual-studio-2017

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which started to misbehave after the last NuGet package updates. The web app uses .NET Framework 4.6.1, and the developer machine is a Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials. One package I use is Stripe.NET for payment processing. Its earlier versions required only `<package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />`. Visual Studio marked that there's a newer version of that (at that time it was `4.3.0`), but when I updated that it pulled in a ton of packages. So I simply reverted back that dependency to `4.0.0`, Stripe didn't require newer.

Then lately I introduced `Nager.Date` to handle work days and holidays. The latest update (v `1.5.0`) of that package requires `"NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1"`. Just like upgrading `System.Net.Http` to `4.3.0`, upgrading to that `Nager.Date` pulls in the ton of packages I mention. In summary: sooner or later I have to cave in and update.

The pulled-in packages:

```
<package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.AppContext" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Console" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Globalization.Calendars" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.IO.FileSystem" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Net.Sockets" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Reflection.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Runtime.Handles" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Text.RegularExpressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Threading.Timer" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
```

I would still be in peace with all of this if in the end I won't be presented with:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in ThruThink.dll
Additional information: Method not found: 'Void System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException..ctor(System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage)'.
```

I couldn't figure out why this happened. Nager.Date owner gave me an idea: he generated the latest package with VS 2017, so I installed that hoping that it'll install some assemblies which will magically solve this exception. But that didn't happen so far.

I don't understand the list of these packages. A lot of them are foundational libraries which supposed to be part of the CLR itself (like System.IO, System.Console, ...) and available without a NuGet package. Maybe one clue is that I see `Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms`, although I'm with .NET 4.6.1, not using .NET Core. I haven't played with .NET Core too much yet, but those packages make sense for .NET Core infrastructure. What's going on?

---

The newest version of `Nager.Date` didn't pull in all of those dependencies and I don't face this problem any more.

Comment: You observed the problem since your upgrade. The problem is that System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException does not have a constructor, at least not the one the libraries are trying to use.

Comment: I know ctor=constructor. What an insane error. Probably a library version mismatch somehow. Is my GAC messed up? How can I fix this situation?

Comment: It is very likely you have a lib version mismatch, one of the classes try to call a constructor which does not exist yet, or no longer exists or was changed from private to public. Unfortunately this is as far as I can go to help you, as this is unclear for me as well (I would have written an answer if I knew the solution).

Comment: I wonder that maybe I should adjust some versions in the Web.config's runtime assembly binding section, or maybe I should add assemblies there?

Comment: Have you found the cause? I have the same runtime errors for .Net Framework 4.6.1 even if compiler is happy. I gave up by throwing different exception.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim some times after my ordeal a new version of Nager.Date corrected the problem by not including stuff which caused errors. Now I'm not on the latest, does it do that again? Since it sometimes happen with other exotic packages, I'm sure it's something about someone has to pay attention to when mastering a package for NuGet repository release, now there basically 3 variations (.NET Core, .NET Standard, ...). We are on the legacy train.

Answer (score 10):

You're hitting System.Net.Http OOB versioning issue, see [Broken System.Net.Http 4.1.1-4.3.0 post-mortem](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/17522). An assembly redirect should fix the problem:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

You may need to redirect to 4.1.1.2 or 4.0.0.0 instead, depending on your project and the libraries you reference.