# C# Method Not Found when async returning Exception

Tags: generics, asynchronous, exception, missingmethodexception

I receive an Exception (Method not found) when attempting to call the following method.

```
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Send(HttpRequestMessage request) {

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClient.SendAsync(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            return response;

        throw new HttpResponseException(response);
    }
```

The failure occurs because of the explicit exception throw on the last line.

If I change

```
throw new HttpResponseException(response);
```

to

```
return null;
```

the method is found.

I'd like to understand the specific reason the method cannot be found when attempting to throw the exception (The generic / async / TaskAwaiter is not able to match all code paths?).

Can you recommend how I can code the method in a way that I can properly throw the exception?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

This turned out to be a red herring. The problem is not related to the method signature, generics, or asynchronous operations. It is instead a .Net Standard Versioning issue the is outlined here:

[Why "Method not found: 'Void System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException..ctor" after package update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896662/why-method-not-found-void-system-web-http-httpresponseexception-ctor-after)

Adding the following binding redirect solved the issue:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```